# How to access stored messages in a MongoDB backed Spring Integration message store?

Tags: mongodb, spring-integration

I implemented a Spring Integration `QueueChannel` backed by a `MongoDbChannelMessageStore`. Message production and my integration flow to consume messages both work as expected.

Now I'm trying to implement a logic that lists and logs all messages currently contained in the message store or queue channel. The messages shall be logged with their POJO payloads (in `toString()` format). The messages shall not be removed from the queue channel by being listed. This logic is supposed to be called during application start-up or on demand.

Here are some code snippets (I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.4).

My message payload:

```
@Data
public class ExampleMessage implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private Instant timestamp;
}
```

My integration configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@Slf4j
public class IntegrationApp {

    private static final String GROUP_ID = "my-group";

    // ... main method omitted

    @Bean
    public MongoDbChannelMessageStore mongoDbChannelMessageStore(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory) {
        return new MongoDbChannelMessageStore(mongoDatabaseFactory, "message-store");
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel channel(MongoDbChannelMessageStore messageStore) {
        MessageGroupQueue messageGroupQueue = new MessageGroupQueue(messageStore, GROUP_ID);
        return new QueueChannel(messageGroupQueue);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(PollableChannel channel) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(channel)
                .handle(message -> log.info("Message received: {}", message.getPayload()),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers
                            .fixedRate(7000, 5000)
                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(1)
                            .taskExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())))
                .get();
    }
```

My message producer:

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
@Slf4j
public class ExampleMessageProducer {

    @Autowired
    private PollableChannel channel;

    private final MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 3000)
    void produceMessage() {
        ExampleMessage exampleMessage = new ExampleMessage();
        messagingTemplate.send(channel, MessageBuilder.withPayload(exampleMessage).build());
        log.info("Message sent: {}", exampleMessage);
    }
}
```

From the public API of Spring Integration messaging, the following approach can be derived for the problem:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class EventListenerBean {

    @Autowired
    MongoDbChannelMessageStore messageStore;

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        Collection<Message<?>> messages = messageStore.getMessageGroup(GROUP_ID).getMessages();
        log.info("# of messages in group: {}", messages.size());
        messages.forEach(m -> log.info("Stored message: {}", m.getPayload()));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach results in an empty collection or stream of messages (probably due to some kind of lazy loading in the message store implementation?).

```
2020-11-03 17:05:42.398  INFO 4748 --- [           main] m.t.s.integration.EventListenerBean      : # of messages in group: 0
2020-11-03 17:05:42.420  INFO 4748 --- [           main] m.t.spring.integration.IntegrationApp    : Started IntegrationApp in 6.557 seconds (JVM running for 7.532)
2020-11-03 17:05:47.533  INFO 4748 --- [pool-1-thread-1] m.t.spring.integration.IntegrationApp    : Message received: ExampleMessage(id=d803b591-2f47-412d-9d64-e8efb424f393, timestamp=2020-11-03T15:43:34.253162Z)
2020-11-03 17:05:48.345  INFO 4748 --- [pool-1-thread-1] m.t.spring.integration.IntegrationApp    : Message received: ExampleMessage(id=7361b7d6-5c36-4801-851e-6d61dc18ebb2, timestamp=2020-11-03T15:43:36.259450500Z)
2020-11-03 17:05:49.348  INFO 4748 --- [pool-1-thread-1] m.t.spring.integration.IntegrationApp    : Message received: ExampleMessage(id=7fe98beb-bd0b-4fda-a2c2-bbab2d80d1e9, timestamp=2020-11-03T15:43:38.265175Z)
2020-11-03 17:05:50.347  INFO 4748 --- [pool-1-thread-1] m.t.spring.integration.IntegrationApp    : Message received: ExampleMessage(id=375d92b6-8746-4478-911a-85b34c2ec2ab, timestamp=2020-11-03T15:43:40.270516100Z)
```

I would like to avoid to query the MongoDB `message-store` collection directly and prefer to use the Spring Integration API.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the specific `MessageGroup`, you can use a `getMessageGroup()` API of the `BasicMessageGroupStore` contract.

Either way it is not good to get access to the low-level resource like database during bean initialization phase like you do with your logs in the `channel` bean definition. You must defer such an operation until the whole application context is ready. Or catch an `ContextRefreshedEvent`, or implement a `SmartLifecycle.start()` contract.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that you are right about `MongoDbChannelMessageStore` and its API. We definitely can't get access to messages from that contract:

```
/**
 * Not fully used. Only wraps the provided group id.
 */
@Override
public MessageGroup getMessageGroup(Object groupId) {
    return getMessageGroupFactory().create(groupId);
}
```

So, we just create a new empty group and no any hooks with whatever is there in the MongoDB collection.

As a workaround I suggest you to have a regular `ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore` as a bean against the same `message-store` collection. This one already provides for us an API to iterate groups and their messages. So, you are going to use `MongoDbChannelMessageStore` for active operations on that `QueueChannel` and  regular `ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore` for reading content of the collection.

We probably need to think about implementing this API in the `ChannelMessageStore`. Doesn't look like there is some harm... Feel free to raise a GH issue for this improvement!

Comment: I totally agree with your last comment and revised my question correspondingly.

Comment: Calling `iterator()` on `mongoDbChannelMessageStore` results in an `UnsupportedOperationException`;
it doesn't seem to be implemented in `AbstractConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore`.

The solution from the 2nd paragraph of your answer is exactly what I'm trying to do in `EventListenerBean`. It results in an empty collection.

Comment: Yes, I see it is not implemented for the `MongoDbChannelMessageStore`. Not sure if it has to be though... Your second argument doesn't mater: it is really likely that you don't have anything in the store to see.

Comment: I don't agree. I'm still able to reproduce the behaviour with an non-empty message store and the code posted in my question above. The log output section in my question was supposed to illustrate that. The application immediately starts consuming messages from the message store after a initial delay and before producing new messages (I disabled the producer for this output). But please note my follow-up below.

Comment: OK. I'll try to  reproduce. Stay tuned!

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Artem. The workaround you proposed worked for me. There's one thing to note: You have to set the collection name for the `ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore` explicitly, because `ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore` and `MongoDbChannelMessageStore` have different default collection names. I'll raise a GH issue for improvement. Regards, Martin.

Comment: True. That's why I said in my answer: "against the same `message-store` collection"

Answer (score 1):

I made some debugging. I cannot see how `MongoDbChannelMessageStore`'s method

```
public MessageGroup getMessageGroup(Object groupId) {
    return this.getMessageGroupFactory().create(groupId);
}
```

(which I use in `EventListenerBean`) can produce anything different than an empty `MessageGroup`.

I tried to change this behaviour by the following initialisation of the `MongoDbChannelMessageStore`:

```
@Bean
public MongoDbChannelMessageStore mongoDbChannelMessageStore(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory) {
    MongoDbChannelMessageStore store = new MongoDbChannelMessageStore(mongoDatabaseFactory, "message-store");
    SimpleMessageGroupFactory messageGroupFactory = new SimpleMessageGroupFactory(GroupType.PERSISTENT) {
        @Override
        public MessageGroup create(Object groupId) {
            return this.create(store, groupId);
        }
    };

    store.setLazyLoadMessageGroups(false);
    store.setMessageGroupFactory(messageGroupFactory);
    return store;
}
```

This is rather a hack, but worked well until it finally ended up in `getMessagesForGroup()` of `AbstractConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore` which, unfortunately, is not implemented.